# Profile page not displaying correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

I was browsing when I came across this on my Stack Overflow profile page.

[image: SO Profile]

The *Next privilege* is now a new line. This is something that I haven't seem before. Thinking that this could've only been something to do with SO, I went to Aviation.SE.

[image: Aviation Profile]

Not much different... I only noticed this today. Is this a bug that has somewhat just stepped in?

Comment: This suddenly happened to me about five minutes ago. Earlier today it was fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oded owes me now for a 5pm-on-a-Friday fix. So, thanks for the report!

A fix is rolling out now. :)

Comment: Profiles across the network thank you, as do I :)